# Cubieboard2 - how do I set GPIO high during boot and keep it high?

Tags: linux, gpio

I am trying to adapt a circuit for soft-power from Raspberry to Cubieboard (http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch). It appears to be working just fine but it needs a pin from the board to be set high while it is running (actually the description is for input with pull-up, but that's not the problem).

I have managed to set the PH15 pin as output high in uBoot script via gpio set 263. However about 3 seconds into the boot process something sets it low back again. The fex file is set correctly to adjust it to output high (tried input with pull-up too) but that appears to kick in several seconds later (about 7-8 seconds in the boot). As a result during the boot process the soft-power circuit just dies reacting to the low state of the pin.

So that is the puzzling question - how to set a pin on the Cubieboard immediately during boot and keep it that way? What brings it down?

Using kernel 3.4.79 with some config options (rtc, drivers, etc - nothing exotic).

Any help appreciated. Modifications to the circuit acceptable too!

Comment: Any Progress on that issue? I have a similar problem with a am335x board. U-Boot pulls my Pin High, something in the Kernel pulls is back to low and some seconds later my Device-Tree pulls it high again... Whos pulling it low again?